# Use Linq to Xml with Xml namespaces

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

I have this code :

```
/*string theXml =
@"<Response xmlns=""http://myvalue.com""><Result xmlns:a=""http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/My.Namespace"" xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""><a:TheBool>true</a:TheBool><a:TheId>1</a:TheId></Result></Response>";*/

string theXml = @"<Response><Result><TheBool>true</TheBool><TheId>1</TheId></Result></Response>";

XDocument xmlElements = XDocument.Parse(theXml);

var elements = from data in xmlElements.Descendants("Result")
               select new {
                            TheBool = (bool)data.Element("TheBool"),
                            TheId = (int)data.Element("TheId"),
                          };

foreach (var element in elements)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.TheBool);
    Console.WriteLine(element.TheId);
}
```

When I use the first value for theXml, the result is null, whereas with the second one, I have good values ...

How to use Linq to Xml with xmlns values ?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

LINQ to XML methods like `Descendants` and `Element` take an `XName` as an argument. There is a conversion from `string` to `XName` that is happening automatically for you. You can fix this by adding an `XNamespace` before the strings in your `Descendants` and `Element` calls. Watch out because you have 2 different namespaces at work.

```
string theXml =
                @"true1";

            //string theXml = @"true1";

    XDocument xmlElements = XDocument.Parse( theXml );
    XNamespace ns = "http://myvalue.com";
    XNamespace nsa = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/My.Namespace";
    var elements = from data in xmlElements.Descendants( ns + "Result" )
          select new
                 {
                     TheBool = (bool) data.Element( nsa + "TheBool" ),
                     TheId = (int) data.Element( nsa + "TheId" ),
                 };

    foreach ( var element in elements )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( element.TheBool );
        Console.WriteLine( element.TheId );
    }
```

Notice the use of ns in `Descendants` and nsa in `Elements`

Comment: xmlElements.Descendants(xmlElements.Root.GetDefaultNamespace() + "Result") may work too...

Comment: Another counterpart to `.GetDefaultNamespace()` is `.GetNamespaceOfPrefix()`, useful for xml like `<foo:Result xmlsns:foo="https://example.com"/>`

Answer (score 27):

You can pass an [XName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.aspx) with a namespace to [Descendants()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.descendants.aspx) and [Element()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.elements.aspx). When you pass a string to Descendants(), it is implicitly converted to an XName with no namespace.

To create a XName in a namespace, you create a XNamespace and concatenate it to the element local-name (a string).

```
XNamespace ns = "http://myvalue.com";
XNamespace nsa = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/My.Namespace";

var elements = from data in xmlElements.Descendants( ns + "Result")
                   select new
                              {
                                  TheBool = (bool)data.Element( nsa + "TheBool"),
                                  TheId = (int)data.Element( nsa + "TheId"),
                              };
```

There is also a shorthand form for creating a XName with a namespace via implicit conversion from string.

```
var elements = from data in xmlElements.Descendants("{http://myvalue.com}Result")
                   select new
                              {
                                  TheBool = (bool)data.Element("{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/My.Namespace}TheBool"),
                                  TheId = (int)data.Element("{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/My.Namespace}TheId"),
                              };
```

Alternatively, you could query against XElement.[Name.LocalName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.localname.aspx).

```
var elements = from data in xmlElements.Descendants()
                   where data.Name.LocalName == "Result"
```

Comment: LocalName doesn't exists in my intellissense

Comment: That conversion from the + operator to xname is grizzly, horrible and an utter abomination. What were MS thinking? Presumably it uses an Expression<Func<whatever>> under the hood - makes me feel ill.

Answer (score 3):

I have several namespaces listed at the top of an XML document, I don't really care about which elements are from which namespace. I just want to get the elements by their names. I've written this extension method.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// A list of XElement descendent elements with the supplied local name (ignoring any namespace), or null if the element is not found.
    /// </summary>
    public static IEnumerable<XElement> FindDescendants(this XElement likeThis, string elementName) {
        var result = likeThis.Descendants().Where(ele=>ele.Name.LocalName==elementName);
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following code to work fine for reading attributes with namespaces in VB.NET:

```
MyXElement.Attribute(MyXElement.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("YOUR_NAMESPACE_HERE") + "YOUR_ATTRIB_NAME")
```

Hope this helps someone down the road.