# C# Xpath Error content:encoded

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, windows-runtime, xmldocument

How can I read a xml element, something like:

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[<blockquote><p>some data here ]]<content:encoded>
```

I want to read the above xml node in C#, but when I use...

```
"content:encoded"
```

.. as the xpath runtime error come:

```
  IXmlNode node = parent.SelectSingleNode("content:encoded");
```

How should I write the xpath for above xml?

Comment: "xpath runtime error come" mind to share error message?

Answer (score 1):

Add a namespace declaration on the top of the module/class.

Comment: CAN YOU EXPLAIN IT
BECAUSE  ALREADY ALL REQUIRED USING STATEMENTS ARE ADDES

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340411/use-linq-to-xml-with-xml-namespaces)

Comment: Did you understand that @RiyalMHH?