# Extract part of a big XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have to extract a part of an XML. My XML file can contain thousands of nodes and I would like to get only a part of it and have this part as an xml string.

My XML structure:

```
<ResponseMessage xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ErrorResponse>
        <Code>SUCCESS</Code>
        <Message>Success</Message>
    </ErrorResponse>
    <OutputXml>
        <Response>
            <Product>
                <child1>xxx</child1>
                <child2>xxx</child2>
                ...
            </Product>
            <Product>
                <child1>xxx</child1>
                <child2>xxx</child2>
                ...
            </Product>
            ...
        </Response>
    </OutputXML>
</ResponseMessage>
```

I'm getting the XML from a webservice like that:

```
...
System.Net.WebResponse wResponse = req.GetResponse();
reqstream = wResponse.GetResponseStream();
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(reqstream);

System.Xml.Linq.XDocument xmlResponse = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

Then I tried to put the XML in a generic collection to process it using linq:

```
int startIndex = 0;
int nbItem = 25;
System.Text.StringBuilder outputXml = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement> partialList =
   xmlResponse.Elements("Response").Skip(startIndex).Take(nbItem);

foreach (System.Xml.Linq.XElement x in partialList)
{
    outputXml.Append(x.ToString());
}
```

My problem is that my list is always empty.

Comment: Note that LINQ XDocument.Parse will construct objects in memory for the entire XML document, even if you're only interested in part of it. If your XML document is so incredibly huge that its object representation won't comfortably fit in available RAM, then you should use the older System.Xml.XmlTextReader to step through the XML tokens as a stream (not constructing objects) until you reach the data you're interested in. It's laborious code, but memory-thrifty when you're looking for a needle in gigabytes of XML data.

Comment: This is a good note... I need to check at the memory usage. I may have to change my code to save RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an LINQ To Xml by using the following code:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> elements = xmlResponse.Root.Element("OutputXml").Element("Response").Elements("Product");

foreach(XElement element in elements)
{
    // Do Work Here
}
```

This will filter the list down to just products and it will select them correctly without using an index. Using indexes with xml is not the greatest idea because the xml can change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I see that I can go through my XML tree using the XmlReader. That may help, but how is it going to be performance like. For example if I want 25 Products starting at index 6500, would I have to increment manually until I reach the good index?

LINQ to XML seems more efficient and probably easier, that's why I was try to use the `Elements().Skip().Take()` methods.

I don't have an object Product on my client side, so I have to stick with generic objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XPathEvaluate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341675.aspx) to read a subtree.

If your list is empty, chances are it is namespace problem, so you did not account for this namespace in your code `xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`. `XDocument`/`XElement` cannot resolve namespaces automatically.

See [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340411/use-linq-to-xml-with-xml-namespaces) on how to use namespaces with LINQ-to-XML.