# How can I parse an Axis XML file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, rest

I am having a bit of a problem trying to parse an XML file generated with Axis Java Web Service in C#. The file has the following format:

```
<ns:getAcctsDetailResponse xmlns:ns="http://paymentdata.com">
    <ns:return xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ax21="http://paymentdata.com/xsd" xsi:type="ax21:AcctsDetail">
    <ax21:Status>15</ax21:Status>
    <ax21:Name>John James</ax21:Name>
</ns:return>
</ns:getCustomerAcctsDetailResponse>
```

I use the code below to try to access the element needed but get the following error:

> **The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.**

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(xml);
string accountName= xDoc.Root.Element("ns:return").Element("ax21:Name").Value;
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You say you're having a bit of a problem - that suggests you've got code which isn't working. Please show it, and say what's going wrong.

Comment: You need to handle the namespaces (the `ns:` and `ax21:`) portions.  See this answer for an example:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2340497/745969

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues:

First, that XML is malformed. The `ns:getAcctsDetailResponse` opening tag doesn't match the `ns:getCustomerAcctsDetailResponse` closing tag. Maybe this is a typo?

Second, you need to do something special for the namespaces. Try something like this:

```cs
XNamespace ns = "http://paymentdata.com"; 
XNamespace ax21 = "http://paymentdata.com/xsd";

XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(xml); 
string accountName = xDoc.Root.Element(ns + "return")
  .Element(ax21 + "Name").Value;
```