# Unable to read weather feed with from weather.gov.sg having an xml namespace in the root tag

Tags: c#

I am trying to read a weather feed from weather.gov.sg. The feed which I get has xmlns attribute set to a uri. If I locally save the xml and remove the xmlns attr value it loads fine, otherwise it still loads but I am not able to get the data from it. Same happens if I try to load the xml directly from the feed url.

Error message - "Sequence contains no elements"

I am using Linq to XML.

any suggestions please?

Thanks,
Deepak

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use Linq to Xml with Xml namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340411/use-linq-to-xml-with-xml-namespaces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(...);
XNamespace ns = "Some.Namepace";
XElement el = doc.Element(ns + "ElementName");
...
```

Don't want to be rude but it wouldn't be a waste of time to read some basics on xml and namespaces.

Comment: Thanks TomB. Yeah Basics should always be first