# Could not read web.sitemap

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, web.sitemap

I have been trying reading web.sitemap using LINQ but could not make it. Following is my web.sitemap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0">
<siteMapNode url="" title="Root">
<siteMapNode url="" title="Manage">
  <siteMapNode url="~/Users.aspx" title="Users" name="10001"/>
  <siteMapNode url="~/Targets.aspx" title="Target" name="10002" />
  <siteMapNode url="~/Cases.aspx" title="Case" name="10003" />
  <siteMapNode url="~/GeoFence.aspx" title="Geofence" name= "10004" />
</siteMapNode>
<siteMapNode url="" title="Configure">
  <siteMapNode url="~/CellDirectory.aspx" title="Cell Directory" name="10005" />
  <siteMapNode url="~/WhiteList.aspx" title="White List"  name="10006"/>
  <siteMapNode url="" title="Options" />
</siteMapNode>
<siteMapNode url="" title="Locate">
  <siteMapNode url="~/FindNow.aspx" title="Find Now"  name="10007"/>
  <siteMapNode url="~/TrackNow.aspx" title="Track Now" name="10008" />
</siteMapNode>
<siteMapNode url="" title="Analyse">
  <siteMapNode url="~/Dashboard.aspx" title="Dashboard" name="10009" />
  <siteMapNode url="~/Search.aspx" title="History" name="10010" />
</siteMapNode>
</siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Following is my code

```
XElement xelement2 = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("~/web.sitemap"));
var urlDescList1 = xelement2.Descendants()                                   
    .Where(sel => (string)sel.Attribute("name").Value == "10001")
    .SelectMany(sel => sel.Elements())
    .Select(nd => new
    {
        title = nd.Attribute("title").Value,
        url = nd.Attribute("url").Value
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

It gives me `null` value. I need to read the node that has name attribute value = `10001`

Comment: The xml contains a namespace. You're not respecting that in your query.

Comment: @J.Steen can you please post query for me..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340411/use-linq-to-xml-with-xml-namespaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your query is just slightly off. You need to ensure the element has the name attribute and `SelectMany(sel => sel.Elements())` is unnecessary.

```
XElement xelement2 = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("~/web.sitemap"));
var urlDescList1 =  
    xelement2.Descendants()                                   
        .Where(sel => sel.Attribute("name") != null && sel.Attribute("name").Value == "10001")=
        .Select(nd => new
        {
            title = nd.Attribute("title").Value,
            url = nd.Attribute("url").Value
        })
        .FirstOrDefault();
```