# Get value from xml element in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am trying to get Absoluteentry tag's value from the below xml string, but its displaying objectrefrence not set exception

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <env:Body>
    <AddResponse xmlns="http://www.sap.com/SBO/DIS">
      <PickListParams>
        <Absoluteentry>120072</Absoluteentry> 
      </PickListParams>
    </AddResponse>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Code

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);
doc.Element("Envelope").Element("Body").Element("AddResponse").Element("PickListParams").Element("Absoluteentry").Value;
```

Comment: You need to set the namespaces for the elements - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2340497/745969 for an example

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use Linq to Xml with Xml namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340411/use-linq-to-xml-with-xml-namespaces)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the XML:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
...
```

That's the `Envelope` element in the namespace with URI `"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"`.

Now look at your code:

```
doc.Element("Envelope")...
```

That's looking for an `Envelope` element that's not in *any* namespace. You should specify the namespace - and the namespaces of the other elements you're looking for:

```
XNamespace env = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope";
XNamespace responseNs = "http://www.sap.com/SBO/DIS";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);
var result = doc.Element(env + "Envelope")
    .Element(env + "Body")
    .Element(responseNs + "AddResponse")
    .Element(responseNs + "PickListParams")
    .Element(responseNs + "Absoluteentry").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Descendants` too. `Descendants` finds children at any level.

```
var result = doc.Element(env + "Envelope")
    .Element(env + "Body")
    .Descendants(responseNs + "Absoluteentry").Value;
```