# C# Get Xelement Attribute Value by Attribute Name

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to get the value of `operating-system` attribute in the xml code below but in all of the solutions I've tried so far from stack, dotnetcurry, and Microsoft, I get either a `NullPointerExecption` or it just returns no values.

Here is the xml data I'm trying to parse:

```
<Report name="Black Workstation" xmlns:cm="http://www.nessus.org/cm">
  <ReportHost name="192.168.1.000>
    <HostProperties>
        <tag name="HOST_END">Wed Jun 29 10:32:54 2016</tag>
        <tag name="LastAuthenticatedResults">1467214374</tag>
        <tag name="patch-summary-total-cves">5</tag>
        <tag name="cpe">cpe:/o:microsoft:windows</tag>
        <tag name="operating-system">Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise Service Pack 1</tag>
    </HostProperties>
  </ReportHost>
</Report>
```

I've tried numerous methods but here are the last two:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.nessus.org/cm";
var operatingSystem = (findings.Where(a => a.Attribute("name").Value == "operating-system")
.Select(a => a.Value));                                        

var operatingSystem = findings.Descendants().Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == ns + "operating-system");
```

Also tried this solution: [Use Linq to Xml with Xml namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2340411/1072681)

I have this method here from the Microsoft tutorial but it only returns true/false and I am not able to manipulate it such that it assigns the value `Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise Service Pack 1` to the `os` variable.

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load(s);
IEnumerable<XElement> findings = xelement.Elements();

var hostProperties = from hp in findings.Descendants("HostProperties")
                     select new
                     {
                         os = (string)hp.Element("tag").Attribute("name").Value == "operating-system",
                     };
```

I've tried using various other Linq-to-Xml queries with the `where` clause like above but they all return `Null` or `no values to enumerate`.

Comment: BTW - really good posing of the question. Giving relevant data to try it out, what you are not getting and also what you have tried :) Improved over time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case you do not need to apply a namespace:

```
var result = XDocument.Load("data.xml")
                      .Descendants("tag")
                      .Where(e => e.Attribute("name").Value == "operating-system")
                      .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;

 //result = Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise Service Pack 1
```

Reading a bit more into it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) you can actually see that even though you define a namespace in your xml none of your elements use it. The namespace you defined (`xmlns:cm`) is applied only to elements with the `cm:` prefix, and their are non of them.

See that if I change your xml as following (namespace is only for `xmlns` and not `xmlns:cm`):

```
<Report name="Black Workstation" xmlns="http://www.nessus.org/cm"> 
  <ReportHost name="192.168.1.000">
  <HostProperties>
    <tag name="HOST_END">Wed Jun 29 10:32:54 2016</tag>
    <tag name="LastAuthenticatedResults">1467214374</tag>
    <tag name="patch-summary-total-cves">5</tag>
    <tag name="cpe">cpe:/o:microsoft:windows</tag>
    <tag name="operating-system">Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise Service Pack 1</tag>
  </HostProperties>
</ReportHost>
</Report>
```

The above code will return `null` and you will have to write is like this:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.nessus.org/cm";
var result = XDocument.Load("data.xml")
                      .Descendants(ns + "tag")
                      .Where(e => e.Attribute("name").Value == "operating-system")
                      .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
```

Comment: Is there another way to do it without `FirstorDefault()`? To where it just selects whatever is there regardless if it is the first time or not?

Comment: @Chris - The `FirstOrDefault()` is just there to get one item out of the collection - that collection in any case contains only 1 item -> only 1 of the 5 tag elements match the where clause. You can also do `ToList()[0].Value` but I think the `FirstOrDefault()?.Value` is a better way to deal with edge cases

Answer (score 0):

please try the following

```
 XDocument document = XDocument.Load("content.xml");
 var name = document.XPathSelectElement("Report/ReportHost/HostProperties/tag[@name='operating-system']").Value;
```